# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

Tags: java, linux, macos

I am trying to install bowtie2, but I fail.

```
sudo apt install bowtie2
```

But I always got error messages:
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

I have been tried:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/Java /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt
```

and

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/Java'
```

But I am still unable to install my bowtie2 function.

Other backgrounds of this question:
Bowtie2 can be downloaded from https://www.java.com/zh-TW/download/

I store the unzipped file on the Desktop.

My Java files are at the below path:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/

My operating system version is macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what your actual Java version is according to macOS. You can use this (macOS exclusive as far as I know) command: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`. Edit: [here](https://medium.com/notes-for-geeks/java-home-and-java-home-on-macos-f246cab643bd) is a blog post about how macOS is _different_... (warning: link hosted on Medium.com, they will likely collect your data).

Comment: This is what I got: Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    9.0.4, x86_64: "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home